# Reading pixel values of jpeg image into an array in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

How to get pixel values of an jpeg image in cuda programming? I tried many ways but I found a function for png image.But i need a function for jpeg file.If there is any function just suggest me otherwise tell me approach how to proceed to it??

Answer (score 3):

CUDA doesn't have any image file support. You will need to find an image decompression/decoding library to transform the image file into a raw bitmap which can be loaded into device memory using the CUDA API